# How to apply right margin/padding to this horizontal scrolling element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a horizontally scrolling div that has a left and right padding of 100px. The left padding seems to be working fine. However, the right side is not visible. What's more, the 50px right margin on the last section is also missing.

What am I missing? Why are both the right padding and margin not respected?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

## Update

Per @chaitanya swami's suggestion, the following is a workaround. I'm still wondering why the above doesn't work as expected.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
}


#carousel {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 100px;
  width: calc(100vw + 400px);
}

.slide {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="carousel">
    <section class="slide"></section>
    <section class="slide"></section>
    <section class="slide"></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you're saying in the comment you mean to say you don't want right side padding from the main div or else that blocks should be in the centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without adding a few additional children, your options are limited.

First is a solution that includes no additional `HTML` children.

1. Remove `flex` from the parent.
2. Remove outer `padding` rule from parent.
3. Add `white-space: nowrap` to the parent.
4. Make the children sections `inline-block`.
5. In order to deal with the unwanted gap space (a symptom of `inline-block`), set the `font-size` of the parent to `0`, restoring it in the children elements to the base font size
6. Add a left/right margin of `100px` to first/last children, respectively.

One step I took to keep the CSS a bit more organized was to assign the `100px` outer spacing to a native CSS variable, since that value is used in more than one place. I think this helps keep the code more readable.

```css
:root {
  --outer-spacing: 100px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;           /* Prevent unwanted inline-block gap spacing */
}

section {
  font-size: 16px;        /* Restore base font size */
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

section:first-of-type {
  margin-left: var(--outer-spacing);
}

section:last-of-type {
  margin-right: var(--outer-spacing);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oxdbpq62/3/

Last, is a solution that is simpler, but adds a `span` before and after the original children. Note: I removed the explicit widths and added them to each shorthand flex declaration in the `flex-basis` slot.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gutter {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

section {
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 15px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="gutter"></span>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <span class="gutter"></span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jw0qz2t3/

Answer (score 5):

You'll need a parent div for that. you will need to define the width of your parent div, which is currently is 100vw.
you can achieve what you want by setting the width 900px or whatever the total width be.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I'm still wondering why the right padding and last right margin aren't being applied.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah may have to do with display flex.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use for css like this

```
<div>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>

<style>
 body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
</style>
```